# How to self-define a function which works for reduce an one-element list?

Tags: python, reduce

I want to return the sum of the subarray in a list of dicts. For example, [{'name': 'a', 'array': [1, 2, 3]}, {'name': 'b', 'array': [3, 3, 4]}], should return 16.

```
a = {'name': 'a', 'array': [1, 2, 3]}
b = {'name': 'b', 'array': [3, 3, 4]}
```

I've defined a function like this:

```
def sum_array(x, y):
    return sum(x['array']) + sum(y['array'])
```

Actually it works well for [a, b]

```
reduce(sum_array, [a, b])    ### this works well and returns 16
```

But for one-element array, it will return itself,

```
reduce(sum_array, [a])  ### this returns {'name': 'a', 'array': [1, 2, 3]}
```

If I want to return 6, how should I define the function?

Comment: Wait, what's up with that edit? Why do you want `reduce(sum_array, [a])` to return 16 instead of 6?

Comment: aha, something was wrong with my head ...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to use `reduce` (you probably shouldn't), this is not a job for `reduce` alone. For each element of the list, you want to take `sum(element['array'])`, and then you want to add those sums together. The `sum(element['array'])` part is a *mapping* operation, and it is a job for `map`, not `reduce`. Adding the sums together is the reduction.

With `map` and `reduce`, the code would look like this:

```
from operator import add

def mapper(d):
    return sum(d['array'])

l = [a] # or l = [a, b], or l = whatever else you want

result = reduce(add, map(mapper, l))
```

It'd be more efficient and readable to use `sum` and a genexp, though:

```
result = sum(sum(x['array']) for x in l)
```

Comment: [Guido van Rossum](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) dropped reduce from the standard library in Python 3 on the grounds that if it cannot be done by list comprehension + `sum()/any()/all()`, it should be written explicitly anyway. That's more an opinion than an argument, but it is convincing to me.

Comment: @Leporello `reduce` is still part of the standard library in Pyython 3, it was just moved from builtins to functools

Answer (score 0):

try this one liner:

```
result = sum([sum(x["array"]) for x in inp_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'name': 'a', 'array': [1, 2, 3]}
b = {'name': 'b', 'array': [3, 3, 4]}

def sum_array(init, x):
    return init + sum(x['array'])

reduce(sum_array, [a], 0)
```

This works well for me.